# Visual Studio Code - compile Javascript on save

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, compilation

The tutor of my video tutorial compiles javascript/react on save with his VS Code editor. Mine dont.
How can I config VS Code to do this?

Remark:
I find solution for typescript "Visual Studio Code - compile on save", but suggested solution does not work for me.

*@added information*:
the project is created with create.react-app. **npm start** opens chrome, and compilation errors are then shown in Chrome's DEV-Console, as noted by Shishani . My tutor has the code compiled on VS Code Terminal console. This offers a quick check of the code compilation before I go to webbrowser, to check for errors there, which seems to me much more intimidating with it's long callstacks.

Comment: It's possible that whatever is compiling the code on save is not integrated with Visual Studio Code, but is a background task he has started on the command line. Something like `npm run watch`, for example, will work with a variety of setups for eg. React or Vue codebases

Comment: my package.json has this:   "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject" but not "watch". Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Omar suggests below: `npm run start` does the job in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your React project with `create-react-app`, and then start it with `npm start`, it compiles automatically on save. Also, if it's not a React project, but just JS/HTML/CSS, you can open your project with the "Live Server" extension in VSCode, and it will update your page every time you save a file in your VSCode *workspace*.

You can even do like I do, and enable constant autosave, with the `AutoSave: afterDelay` setting in VSCode  (if you dare), and then set the save delay to a super small number (mine is 2ms) so you don't even need to hit save anymore (go to `File>Preferences>Settings>[Search "Auto Save"]`).
[image]

Comment: I used a console external of VS Code. Thus the compilation errors display my tutor get's in the VS terminal appear for me on this external console. Now as you explained the backstage workflow I understand. If I want to see compilation error inside VS code I just npm start the rig here :-).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created react project using there official cli tool (create-react-app) then on saving js files it gets re-compile. This is because they are using webpack bundler behind the scene.

If you have created normal html or js files without any such cli tools then it won't work directly, You have to use some kind of bundler with dev-server support to do it.

[Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)! is a great bundler to use without configuration